# VBA: How create a loop altering dates

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet of data where each row has been copied and pasted three time.  Each row has a date in column S.  Within these sets of three, the first row will remain the original date, the second row will be one month later than the original date, and the third row will be two months after the original date.

How do I turn this into a loop that repeats the process for the entire sheet?  My problem lies with the DateAdd function.  I''m getting a compile error on that function (never used it before).  Thanks in advance!  Here is the code that I have thus far:

```
Sub DateChange()


Dim r As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For r = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
With Cells(r, 1).EntireRow
    .Copy
    .Resize(2).Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
End With
Cells(r + 1, "S").Value = DateAdd("m", 1, Cells(r, "S"))
Cells(r + 2, "S").Value = DateAdd("m", 2, Cells(r, "S"))
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to select cells and use `ActiveCell` instead of `Cells(r, c)`? In general, the latter tends to work better.

Comment: No reason,  I'll change it to Cells(r,c) haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative to DateAdd which is erroring for reasons currently unknown.

```
Sub Macro()

Dim r As Long, d As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For r = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    With Cells(r, 1).EntireRow
        .Copy
        .Resize(2).Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
    d = Cells(r, "S").Address
    Cells(r + 1, "S").Value = Evaluate("date(year(" & d & "),month(" & d & ")+1,day(" & d & "))")
    Cells(r + 2, "S").Value = Evaluate("date(year(" & d & "),month(" & d & ")+2,day(" & d & "))")
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your code works:

```
Sub DateChange()
    For r = 3 To 1000 Step 3
        Sheets("NameOfYourSheet").Range("S" & r) = "=DATE(YEAR(R[-1]C),MONTH(R[-1]C)+1,DAY(R[-1]C))"
        Sheets("NameOfYourSheet").Range("S" & r).AutoFill Destination:=Range("S3:S4"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: My original code worked but this did not.  Is their anything that I should have included in this?  And how would you dim your variables?  Thank you!

Comment: This loop wont work because you are looping for every row, the OP needs a loop for every 3 rows (if I understand the question correctly)

Comment: Yes, exactly.  A loop for every 3 rows is needed

Comment: My bad. Added `Step 3`, which means `r` will increase by 3, every iteration.